# $\mathcal{F}$-- twists of Lie algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am trying to figure out with Drindfel's Opers. Let us consider Lie group $G$ and $G$ -- bundle $\mathcal{F}$ on the smooth algebraic curve $Y$. Can anybody help me and clarify definition of the $\mathcal{F}$ --  twist of $\mathfrak{g}$ where $\mathfrak{g}$ is Lie algebra of $G$.

Comment: The product $\mathcal{F} \times \mathfrak{g}$ has a natural $G$-equivariant structure by the right action on $\mathcal{F}$ and the adjoint action on $\mathfrak{g}$.  The twist is given by fppf descent.

Comment: I've made out missing constructions by virtue of your comment.